# Zend form populate method

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a Zend form below is the code

```
 public function editAction()
{
    try 
    {
        $data = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->read();
        $this->view->UserInfo = $data['UserInfo'];
        $this->view->Account = $data['Account'];
        $UserEditForm = $this->getUserEditForm();
        $this->view->UserEditForm = $UserEditForm;
        $params = $this->_request->getParams();
        if ($params['user'])
        {
            $UserResult = $this->_user_model->getUserData($params['user']);
            $UserAddressResult = $this->_user_model->getAddressData($params['user']);
            $UserInfo = Array(
                'UserId'        =>  $UserResult['user_id'],
                'EmailAddress'  =>  $UserResult['email'],
                'UserName'      =>  $UserResult['username'],
                'Title'         =>  $UserResult['Title'],
                'FirstName'     =>  $UserResult['firstname'],
                'LastName'      =>  $UserResult['lastname'],
                'Gender'        =>  $UserResult['gender'],
                'DateOfBirth'   =>  date('m/d/Y', strtotime($UserResult['dateofbirth'])),
                'AddressLine1'  =>  $UserAddressResult['address_1'],
                'AddressLine2'  =>  $UserAddressResult['address_2'],
                'City'          =>  $UserAddressResult['city'],
                'State'         =>  $UserAddressResult['state_id'],
                'PostalCode'    =>  $UserAddressResult['postcode'],
                'Country'       =>  $UserAddressResult['country_id'],
                'CompanyName'   =>  $UserAddressResult['company'],
                'WorkPhone'     =>  $UserAddressResult['workphone'],
                'HomePhone'     =>  $UserAddressResult['homephone'],
                'Fax'           =>  $UserAddressResult['fax'],
                'IsDashboardUser'   => $UserResult['is_dashboard_user']
            );
            $UserEditForm->populate($UserInfo);
            $this->view->UserEditForm = $UserEditForm;
        }
        if ($this->_request->isPost())
        {
            $values = $this->_request->getPost();
            unset($values['Save']);
            if ($UserEditForm->isValid($values))
            {
                $Modified_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $UserData = $this->_user_model->CheckEmail($values['EmailAddress']);
                $UpdateData = $this->_user_model->UpdateUserData($UserData['user_id'], $values, $Modified_date, $data['UserId']);
                if ($UpdateData != null)
                {
                    return $this->_helper->redirector('userlist','index','user');
                }
            }
        }  
    }
    catch (Exception $exception)
    {
        echo $exception->getCode();
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }   
}
```

Because my form elements names are different then my table field names i have to declare a Array $UserAddressResult see above code to match the table field name with form element name.

Is there a another way to populate form without declaring this array.

Please don't suggest that i have to keep my table field name and form element name same. I cannot do that as per our naming convention standards.

Comment: Adjust your naming convention standards, maybe? ;)

Comment: if this is something used a lot I'd be tempted to at least make a method or class to normalize this data, maybe in one of your models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to keep same name of form elements as per our table fields name. For now this is the only solutions i feel. if i come across any other solutions in future will update here...

Thanks for all your replies....

Answer (score 1):

Your naming convention is inconsistent. If it were consistent, you could perhaps use a simple regular expression to transform column names. But you can't, so you will have to do it manually one way or the other.

If you need to construct this array of values in more than one place in your code, you should consider moving the logic to the form itself (extend it with a `public function populateFromUserAndResult($userResult, $userAddress)`) or an action helper.